# JCE security provider in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, jce

We have a problem using a custom JCA implementation in our OSGi bundle. The JCA implementation that we are forced to use by our customer leads to a class loader memory leak. This prevents the deployment and usage of it in our bundle, because we quickly run into a perm gen space problem.

The proposed solution from the JCA provider is to put the JAR in the jre/lib/ext folder, but it is not loaded from there. This is due, as far as I know, to the OSGi (Eclipse equinox) class loader policy to have the bootstrap classloader as the parent of each bundle classloader, which excludes the extension class loader that loads from the jre/lib/ext folder. I.e. no bundle ever sees anything in the jre/lib/ext folder.

Is there a way to get Eclipse equinox to load a jar that is registered as a security provider, only once, such that all bundles or a specific bundle can see that provider? The fact that the JCA library is not unloaded via OSGi could be tolerated in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the system packages and add the packages from the JCA-custom.jar.

You can define which packages should be included in several ways.

- You create a profile for equinox and define the packages. You can find examples for each jdk versions in the eclipse.osgi jar. For example, look for JavaSE-1.6.profile and try finding the entry org.osgi.framework.system.packages
- You can define it as a system variable when you start your OSGi container. The system variable is the same: -Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages=*package names separated by comma*